# How to store a URL and Visit a URL in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, scripting, greasemonkey

Alright well I'm still a very new coder in Greasemonkey and just know a little so please try to explain your best.

What I'm trying to do is make it so i have a variable that Greasemonkey gets when the script is first used and the variable is that URL that the page is on now  and then it will call on the variable and go to that URL again.

So basically i need to know:
How to store a URL and Visit a URL.

I hope i was clear enough.

Comment: Perhaps you'll get a response if you wodk your title as an actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not clear.  Do you just want to continually refresh the page?

Anyway, re:   `"So basically i need to know: How to store a URL and Visit a URL."`
...

```
//--- Store a URL.
GM_setValue ("MyURL", window.location.href);


//--- Visit a URL.
var MyURL               = GM_getValue ("MyURL");
window.location.href    = MyURL;
```

Reference [the Greasemonkey Manual](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual%3aAPI).

Comment: I need to know how to do both Store a url and later visit a url
And im testing this now